# How do I join these tables while displaying multiple columns of one table on the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a price list table (ITM1) that looks like this:

```
ItemCode    PriceList   Price
-----------------------------
5740660     1           2.06
5740660     2           3.05
5740660     3           3.05
5740660     4           3.05
5740660     5           2.95
5740660     10          2.15
5740661     1           12.86
5740661     2           19.48
5740661     3           19.48
5740661     4           24.35
5740661     5           11.69
5740661     10          13.79
```

And an information table (OITM) like this:

```
ItemCode    Description            QryGroup11
---------------------------------------------
5740660     Seal, Head Locating    Y
5740661     Screw, Head Locating   N
```

I found a query here for displaying my prices like this:

```
Item No.    Actual Cost AMG Retail  Mil Wholesale   Mil Retail  AMG Dealer  Civ Retail
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5740660     2.06        3.05       3.05             3.05            1.83            2.15
5740661     12.86       19.48      19.48            24.35           11.69           13.79
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    ItemCode
    ,MAX(price1) as 'Actual Cost'
    ,MAX(price2) as 'AMG Retail'
    ,MAX(price3) as 'Mil Wholesale'
    ,MAX(price4) as 'Mil Retail'
    ,MAX(price5) as 'AMG Dealer'
    ,MAX(price10) as 'Civ Retail'
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ItemCode 
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 1 THEN price END AS Price1
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 2 THEN price END AS Price2
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 3 THEN price END AS Price3
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 4 THEN price END AS Price4
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 5 THEN price END AS Price5
         ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 10 THEN price END AS Price10
     FROM ITM1) AS ITM1
GROUP BY 
    ItemCode
```

My question:

How do I join my tables to display the `Description` for the item and add a where clause to display only `QueryGroup11 = 'Y'`?

I understand inner joins and can get great results from multiple tables but with the query above I can't quite seem to get the information to display without errors.

Thanks for a great SQL Server resource!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add a regular `JOIN` with the `OITM` table, `GROUP BY` the fields you want to use and add a `HAVING` to do the filtering after the `GROUP BY` has been done.

Extending your existing query that'd be something like;

```
SELECT ITM1.ItemCode, Description
  ,MAX(price1) as 'Actual Cost'
  ,MAX(price2) as 'AMG Retail'
  ,MAX(price3) as 'Mil Wholesale'
  ,MAX(price4) as 'Mil Retail'
  ,MAX(price5) as 'AMG Dealer'
  ,MAX(price10) as 'Civ Retail'
FROM
(
  SELECT ItemCode 
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 1 THEN price END AS Price1
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 2 THEN price END AS Price2
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 3 THEN price END AS Price3
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 4 THEN price END AS Price4
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 5 THEN price END AS Price5
  ,CASE WHEN PriceList = 10 THEN price END AS Price10
  FROM ITM1 
) AS ITM1
JOIN OITM ON ITM1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
GROUP BY ITM1.ItemCode, OITM.Description, OITM.QryGroup11
HAVING QryGroup11='Y'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ba5c/9).

Comment: Worked perfectly...  I was stuck on the idea of a where statement and had my joins in the wrong place. 

Thanks Joachim!

Comment: Having or Where work the same here. Also you don't really need the inline view at all. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ba5c/11)